# Is it possible to see domains in a metal/magnet under microscope

Tags: electromagnetism

I was just curious to know that is it possible to see domains of a magent/metal in motion on being magnetized, under microscope. If there is someone who has access to microscopes, can help me out on this. I was thinking of buying one.
Question is lil stupid but I am putting it here because I know no better place !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have a couple of options without have to resort to a microscope.  One of the most interesting is [Magnetic Field Viewing Film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field_viewing_film) which should allow one to view magnetic fields easily over large domains.  The film is [pretty responsive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMggixEu0q0&feature=related), so it would likely allow one to view domain formation in larger materials.

An interesting way to viewing magnetic effects is to use an [old computer crt and some magnets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bliKAQMq5Yc).  If you wanted to get down to the [nano scale, that is possible too,](http://www.psi.ch/media/moving-monopoles-caught-on-camera) but probably out of most people's budget.  The [viewing film is definitely budget friendly](http://www.arborsci.com/magnetic-field-viewer-film-9in-x-7-2in).

Comment: +1, the viewing film is a great tool to visualize magnetism and is cheap as well (5€).

Comment: thanks for suggestion but actually I was just wondering if I can see the domains getting aligned...!

Comment: @rafiki [A Kerr microscope is what you might thinking of.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain#Observing_domains)    [Here is another view.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Moving_magnetic_domains_by_Zureks.gif)

Comment: @HalSwyers: ya I have seen that but is must be quite different and highly specialized for that purpose..but thanks for links !